# Are multiple class tags are valid in HTML?

Tags: html, css

The following HTML is right or wrong?

```
<div class="navbar" class="menu">foo</div>
```

Do the 2 classes both work?

Answer (score 5):

To specify two classes you can give space between them like

```
<div class="navbar menu">foo</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`class` is not a tag but an attribute. Having multiple attributes of the same name is an error.

> [...]; if there is already an attribute on the token with the exact same name, then this is a duplicate-attribute parse error and the new attribute must be removed from the token.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#attribute-name-state

Usually browsers will just ignore the second attribute. So in your case, `class="menu"` is ignored and only the `navbar` class is applied. To use both classes write `class="navbar menu"`.